# Using Perl module IO::Uncompress::AnyUncompress

Tags: perl, 7zip

I wish to use Perl module IO::Uncompress::AnyUncompress, which is documented here : http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Uncompress/AnyUncompress.html.

However, this documentation seems to elude the fact that a compressed archive (.zip, .7z) contains a tree of compressed files. I would like to extract only a single file from the archive and not the full archive, for example :

```
my $archivename = 'archive.7z';
my $filetoextract = './bin/file.lib';

my $archive = new IO::Uncompress::AnyUncompress($archivename);
my $filecontent = $archive->extract($filetoextract);
```

However, the API does not seem to have such an `extract()` fonction, neither a function that would return the list of files contained in the archive.

Have I missed something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IO::Uncompress::AnyUncompress` only deals with a single compressed byte stream. You'll need a module like [`Archive::Any`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive%3a%3aAny), [`Archive::Any::Lite`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive%3a%3aAny%3a%3aLite), or [`Archive::Libarchive::XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive%3a%3aLibarchive%3a%3aXS).

Comment: Unfortunately, `Archive::Any` only supports zips & tars.

Comment: `Archive::Libarchive::Any` seems to be the solution but installation failed on Windows; dependency `Alien::Libarchive` failed.

Comment: Hence my problem is not solved but you still gave a good answer to my question !